# Sync Google Calendar with my own Calendar app on Android

Tags: android, google-calendar-api, android-calendar

Hello I'm stuck on this past few days with searching a lot, now I'm confusing what to do.

**Trying to do:** Created my own calendar and show all events on Calendar. I had all events in XML file for now, everything works fine. Now I'm connecting my calendar app with my OWN google calendar account to fetch **(read only)** all events from my own Google Calendar account because I dont want to use the XML file anymore. It's not a good idea when I want to update events later on. I dont want users have to enter username/pass to connect with Google Calendar. I would like to HARDCODED it.

**Problems:** I'm done something like this for iphone by using G-Data Google Api, it works exactly what I want to. However, G-Data Google Api **is not compatible** with Android. Then I searched and found ppl recommend use Google_api_java_client instead.

This is [link](http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/calendar-android-sample/instructions.html) where it can connect with a google Calendar account by letting user enter username& password. However, this is not I want. I want to hard coded username and password inside my code, but they are using OAuth then I can't hard coded my username/pass. I also tried ClientLogin from this [link](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/ClientLogin), but it doesn't work too. It keeps throw me error ["GoogleTransport cannot be resolved"](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/prediction-api-discuss/B3oJevuTkhI). I searched solution for this error, ppl recommend me back to OAuth. This is really make me confusing now.

I hope someone experienced this and have solution, please help me/ guide me how to implement this on android. I just want to read data from my own google calendar account only, PLEASE not from native calendar app.

Last information that I found is by sending an authenticated GET request to the allcalendars feed [URL.](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v2/developers_guide_protocol#RetrievingAllCalendars) However, I never done this, if you think it should work, please assist me with that.

I really appreciated any helps. Thank you very much.

Comment: Not really sure to understand yet your problem. You want to create an Android calendar on each device you install your app, that is displaying the events backed by YOUR google calendar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already got the Android calendar creation part right, you now only need to read events from your google calendar to add them to your newly created Android calendar.

It's easy.

1. Make your calendar public from the [Google calendar web app](https://www.google.com/calendar/render). (anyway embedding your login/pwd in your app is a bad idea, anyone could steal it).
2. On the "agenda parameter" page, near the **Public Calendar URL** section, you will be able to copy the public *AgendaId* (in the form `xxxYYYzzz@group.calendar.google.com`).
3. From your app, do an http GET request to this url https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/AgendaId%40group.calendar.google.com/public/full?alt=json&orderby=starttime&max-results=15&singleevents=true&sortorder=ascending&futureevents=true (replace *AgendaId* by the real value) and you will be able to read future events in json format.
4. To tweak the format (json/xml) or the number of returned entries, please read the documentation here: https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/2.0/reference#Queries

Also, note this is the old API. The new API needs you to register an account to use it and is limited to 10 000 free requests per day.

Comment: I think you got what I need. Give me sometimes, will double check before i mark your answer as an accept answer. I was over think for this.

Comment: What is the new API you are talking about? 10000 free request/day is not much.

Comment: I think Google now want us to use the v3 calendar API  https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/ but as you can see in the API console, there is a courtesy limit: https://code.google.com/apis/console/ (click on services tab). However I think the public calendar link will continue to work for a long long time.

Comment: Actually Google accepts 1,000,000 queries per day. =) https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/pricing