# Sync a google calendar on my app via internet

Tags: android, json, google-calendar-api

I would like to synchronize a google calendar on my app. The calendar is not stored on the phone since it will be a public calendar. I want, for example: a company manages the calendar on their google account and all the costumers can consult it on the company's app. The calendar account will be different than the user's phone account.Is that possible?

I tried the CalendarContract but I only was able to synchronize it with local events and calendars, located in the phone. Maybe I should use JSON and parse it? Any suggestion or good reference? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are many resource that you can refer like. [`Google Calendar API`](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/?csw=1), for [`Authentication`](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/Android#Authentication) and for [`Another reference`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249053/pulling-data-from-google-calendar-on-android-in-json) and [`Sync own Calendar`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12480573/sync-google-calendar-with-my-own-calendar-app-on-android)

Comment: just to add, since the user will not own the calendar he is syncing with, the calendar must be shared with him.

Comment: It is impossible to share the calendar with all the users. I want, for example, a company manages the calendar through google account and all the costumers can consult it on the company's app.